# In this Singleton decorator implementation, when is the __init__ called, and what exactly does it do?

Tags: python, singleton, decorator, init

in the below implementation of Singleton, there is an `__init__` in the Singleton class.
what triggers it, and what does it do behind the scenes?

```
class Singleton:

    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._cls = cls

    def Instance(self):
        try:
            return self._instance
        except AttributeError:
            self._instance = self._cls()
            return self._instance

    def __call__(self):
        raise TypeError('Singletons must be accessed through `Instance()`.')

    def __instancecheck__(self, inst):
        return isinstance(inst, self._cls)
```

```
@Singleton
class DBConnection(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize your database connection here."""
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Database connection object'
```

```
c1 = DBConnection.Instance()
c2 = DBConnection.Instance()

print("Id of c1 : {}".format(str(id(c1))))
print("Id of c2 : {}".format(str(id(c1))))

print("c1 is c2 ? " + str(c1 is c2))
```

the output of the last code block is:

```
Id of c1 : 139699882512960
Id of c2 : 139699882512960
c1 is c2 ? True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
@Singleton
class DBConnection(object):
```

Are the equivalent of:

```
class DBConnection(object):
    # rest of class elided
DBConnection = Singleton(DBConnection)
```

So you can see from the last line above that `Singleton` is called like a function, which is how you instantiate a class, which is when `__init__()` is called.